# Need to reconfigure Process builder formula

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, process-builder

Person Accounts is enabled

Have multiple record types on Accounts (a few for 'Accounts' and a few for 'Person Accounts'

They have an old process that was implemented, but we re-architected the objects and trying to replicated old Process Builders and workflows

What I need is simple (I Think):

This is the old way it was done:
The **Field:Lawyer Changes** value populated when ever the **Field: Lawyer** changed when there is 1 or more **Field: Contracts Currently Open**.

So essentially Previous Lawyers name was changed from Previous Lawyer to new Lawyer on a new text field if a contract is currently open as you can see from the previous configuration.
(i.e. Changed Lawyer from Andrew Sanchez to Tom Arnold)

*Old Object:*

**Accounts**

*Old Fields Used for this process:*

**Lawyer**
(Custom Field: Lawyer__c / Data type: Lookup / Related to: Account)

**Lawyer Changes**
(Custom Field: Lawyer_Changes__c / Data Type: Text Area

**Contracts Currently Open**
(Custom Field: Contracts_Currently_Open__c / Data Type: Roll-up summary / Summarized Object: Opportunity / Filter Criteria: Stage = Funding Queue, Case Funded, Impaired / Summary type: Count)

**OLD CONFIG**
[image]

[image]

Object: ACCOUNT
Start the Process : When a record is created or edited
[image]

Criteria Name: Lawyer Changed 
Criteria for Executing Actions: Conditions are met

(SET CONDITIONS Below) <--- If you cant see it in picture

```
[Account].Lawyer__c / Is changed / Boolean / True
[Account].RecordType.Name / Equals / String/ Plantiff
[Account].Contracts_Currently_Open__c / Greater than or equal / Number / 1
Conditions: All of the Conditions are met (AND)
```

[image]

Action Name: Update Lawyer Changes
Record: Account
Criteria for Updating Records: No Criteria-Just update the records!
Field: Layer Changes / Type: Formula / Value: (FORMULA BELOW)

```
"Changed Lawyer from "  & if(not(isBlank(PRIORVALUE([Account].Lawyer__c ))) ,PRIORVALUE([Account].Lawyer__c.FirstName ) & " " & PRIORVALUE([Account].Lawyer__c.LastName ) & " to " ,"") &  if(not(isBlank([Account].Lawyer__c)), [Account].Lawyer__c.FirstName & " " & [Account].Lawyer__c.LastName ,"")& "; "
& PRIORVALUE([Account].Lawyer_Changes__c)
```

[image]

**NEW CONFIG So Far...**

[image]
[image]

The NEW WAY needs to be this (which is very similar):

The **Field:Lawyer Changes** value populated when ever the **Field: Attorney** changes when the **Field: Status** is  either Open or In Progress. Previous Lawyers name was changed from Previous Lawyer to new Lawyer on a new text field if a contract is currently open or in progress.
(i.e.[Field: Lawyer Changes]  Changed Lawyer from Andrew Sanchez to Tom Arnold

New Object:

**Court Case / Court_Case__c**

New Fields Used for this process:

**Attorney**
(Custom Field: Attorney__c / Data type: Lookup / Related to: Account)

**Lawyer Changes**
(Custom Field: Lawyer_Changes__c / Data Type: Text Area

**Status**

```
​​​​​​​(Custom Field: Status__c / Data Type:Formula:
if( or( text(Funding_Status__c) = "Repaid" , text(Funding_Status__c) = "Written Off"),"Complete",
if(and(Total_Fundings__c = 0 ,or(text(Case_Stage__c) = "Settled - Won" , text(Case_Stage__c) = "Lost")),"Closed",
if(Total_Fundings__c > 0,"In Progress","Open")))
```

Basically I just need advice/help on how to go about this. Should I do a process builder? Or Apex? If so, can anyone help me out with a solution?

Comment: Hi SFMike, welcome to SFSE. Just so you know, we have a format here (see [ask]) that looks for very specific questions. Right now, it looks like you've actually got 90% of what you need - you have a working Process that gives you the structure of the solution, and you just need to rebuild it with a new object and a different criterion. Could you try to streamline your question with an [edit] to focus on a specific issue you're having as you make those changes? I'm sure the community can help you.

Comment: Hey David! Thank you for your input. I also appreciate you fixing my questions layout.

With that being said, I am the solo Admin who has a bit of a gap in my SF Admin experience, so my formula skills have gotten a bit rusty. Can you or anyone else on here give me a bit of some hand holding over here? It would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks again!